# Add a scroll bar to a JList?

Tags: java, swing

How do you add a JList to a JScrollPane ?

Comment: [Here is how to add scroll bar to list][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940838/adding-scrollbar-to-jlist

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for a working example. That is start with the tutorials for the basics, not the forum.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Put your `JList` in a `JScrollPane`

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
JList list = new JList();
scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
```

Comment: first JScrollPane and then JList on it ?

Comment: first I opened my design page(JFrame) then ı added JScrollPane on it I put Jlist they both in the same size but nothing has changed:(

Comment: @hiii It sounds like you are getting confused with a visual form designer. What IDE are you using?