# Add scroll on my JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

My ScrollPane won't show to my JList. I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522807/add-a-scroll-bar-to-a-jlist), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621349/adding-a-scrollbar-to-jlist-in-swing), and many other ways to add a scroll on my jlist but it wont just show. Here is the sample of my code.

```
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list_1);
    list_1 = new JList();
    scrollPane.setViewportView(list_1);
    list_1.setBounds(16, 94, 579, 248);
    contentPane.add(list_1);
    contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

My JList consists of array of files (paths) that came from my database.

Comment: Put `JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list_1);` AFTER your `JList` has been created , because it is `null` when you pass it to the `JScrollPane` .

Comment: I have already tried that but still, it's not working

Comment: If you need more help then post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. So you need a frame with a JList with some data. The whole class should be less than 20 lines of code.

Answer (score 5):

The list needs to be created before being added to the scrollpane. The code should be:

```
list_1 = new JList();
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list_1);
//list_1 = new JList();
```

A component can only have a single parent. The code should be:

```
//contentPane.add(list_1); // this will remove the list from the scrollpane
contentPane.add(scrollPane);
```

Don't use setBounds():

```
list_1.setBounds(16, 94, 579, 248);
```

The scrollpane uses its own layout manager so the above code does nothing. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

3 problems with 6 lines of code. I suggest you start by reading the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for more information and working examples.

The tutorial is full of basic Swing information and will help you get started with simple examples containing better structured code.

Comment: I have already tried everything that you have said but it still doesn't work. If I remove the `contentPane.add(list_1);`, nothing will show.

Comment: @Salvatore, no you haven't tried everything. Did you read the tutorial? Did you download the working examples? Maybe your problem is that you are using a null layout? Read the tutorial, download the working examples and modify that code to do what you want. Start with a working example. If you make a changes and it stops working then you know where the problem is.